# Jenkins: Is there a way to get a list of all project URL

Tags: jenkins, project

I am asked to produce a wiki has links to all projects in Jenkins. Is there a way to produce the list of all projects URL in a folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to /api/json?pretty=true if you want to see all of your projects.

Or

Go to /view/your_folder_name/api/json?pretty=true if you want to see just the projects in that folder.

Or

Scroll to the bottom of any of your jenkins folders -> Click "REST API" -> Click either "JSON API" or "XML API"

There you will see a list of all of your projects with their urls.

Comment: The above solution only shows the projects in the folder being accessed, and does not make a recursive listing (eg: If I access the `api/json` path on root folder, I don't see the list of folders there, but none of the projects inside each folder. Is there a way to make this recursive and get a full listing of everything that exists in Jeknins?